# Converting .java file (source code) to PDF?

Tags: java, pdf

I cannot find a decent solution to this.

I need to convert my source code to a PDF. No printing; just the PDF.

I found [Enscript for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/enscript.htm) but cannot get it's overcomplicated being to work. Any help?

Comment: Copy code from Eclipse, paste to Word, export to PDF. Done.

Comment: By the way, is this a programming question? Or are you asking about tools?

Comment: @nhahtdh it wont support

Comment: @NK123: What won't support? FYI, it comes with code highlighting in Word.

Comment: open with google chrome save as pdf

Comment: @nhahtdh how would we export to PDF from Word?

Comment: @NK123: From Word 2007, there is save as PDF.

Comment: OpenOffice and LibreOffice can export to PDF out of the box

Comment: i have tried now, it changes logo only.

Comment: Solution for bulk files: https://stackoverflow.com/q/39256944/15438360 IntelliJ solution. I think there is also an option in Eclipse.

Answer (score 3):

Just download a pdf printer like...

[pdf printer](http://www.bullzip.com/products/pdf/info.php) Open the java file in something like Eclipse so you can syntax highlighting, paste to Notepad++, print to pdf.

Comment: Word doesn't support syntax highlighting for programming languages.

Comment: changed answer, use Notepad++ as that does

Comment: Why paste to Notepad++? You can directly print in Eclipse.

Comment: Ah, I originally wrote that but I wasn't sure if the printing in Eclipse was any good etc (or worse that notepad++), but yes, you can just print in Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

I think it helps you `itext`

[SEE](http://itextpdf.com/examples/)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @Cairnarvon is compulsory to write exact code? i have put the reference link, have seen so many post where links are answers.

Comment: None of the answers to this question are any good, to be honest, and neither is the question itself. Yours is the one I came across in the Low Quality queue, though, so yours is the one on which I commented.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a Windows OS, you can use [Some Text to PDF Converter](http://www.somepdf.com/some-text-to-pdf-converter.html). It's free, has a GUI and is simple to use.