# Intellij print all classes as PDF

Tags: pdf, text, intellij-idea, printing

My professor wants to get the code of my Library Management project not only as .java files but also as a one PDF file. Is there any way to do that in Intellij? I have a lot of classes, and I would like to avoid having to click and print every one of them separately.

Is there any workaround? I am using Mac OS. If I select the folder where the code is, the print button shows greyed out.

Answer (score 15):

1. Select the directory that contains all of your source code. If your code is scattered around different directories you will have to either print it in batches or drop all the files you want to print into one temporary folder and select it.
2. Click `File` -> `Print`.
3. In the menu that pops up select `All files in directory` option. [This help page](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/print.html) explains all the options in this menu. Click `Print`.
4. To save all the code as PDF instead of your physical printer select a virtual PDF printer. Windows 10 has "Microsoft Print to PDF" installed by default. If you don't have one, you can pick one for your OS on [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_virtual_printer_software)

Comment: I am using Mac OS. If I select the folder where the code is, the print button shows greyed out. I can click on it.

Comment: @DavidVV Do you have a printer? Maybe it's greyed out because there are no printers on your system. If that's the case installing a PDF printer for Mac like [this one](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfwriterformac/) will help.

Comment: @DavidVV what if you simply select the `Print` option for a single file and then then chose `All files in directory...` & `Include subdirectories`?

Comment: On Mac as of IntelliJ IDEA CE 2020.1.1, "Open in Preview" doesn't work but "Save as PDF" does.

Answer (score 1):

Set up a fictional printer on your mac.

1. Go to printers and scanners in system preferences.
2. Add a new printer.
3. Click the globe(network) icon.
4. Address: 0.0.0.0

   Protocol: Airprint

   Use: Select Software -> Epson 24-pin series, or whatever you feel like
   choosing
5. Add. Continue to add although warnings are displayed.

Now, you can "save to pdf" from IntelliJ Idea—no more weird errors.